# Variable with double value in python is it possible?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How can I fix this script

When playlist in the format `'http://............../playlist.m3u'`string not found
When playlist in the format `'C:\Users\******\*****\playlist.m3u'`   not works
When playlist in the format `'file:///C:\Users\******\*****\playlist.m3u'`  works
He is currently working only with files from hard drive but when I select a menu from xml files on the network stops working, how can I have

```
playlist = 'http://............../playlist.m3u'
```

and

```
playlist = 'file:///C:\Users\******\*****\playlist.m3u'
```

simultaneously, is it possible? Thank you

```
def GETPLAYLIST():
    playlistset = int(addon.getSetting('playlistset')) + 1
    playlist = addon.getSetting('playlist' + str(playlistset))
    playlist = "file:///" + playlist
    return playlist
```

Comment: `replace('\', '/')` and just focus on `'/'`?

Comment: I did not understand what changes should I do, I'm sorry

Comment: these urls are strings and strings in python have the `replace` method. Google some..

Comment: Sorry but I still do not understand how I should use the replace, I tried to replace  playlist = `"file:///" + playlist` con  `replace('\', '/')` but it does not work

Comment: `playlist = playlist.replace('\', '/')`

Comment: I'm sorry but I run this change but it does not work, maybe I'm wrong again?                                                                                                 `def GETPLAYLIST():
    playlistset = int(addon.getSetting('playlistset')) + 1
    playlist = addon.getSetting('playlist' + str(playlistset))
    playlist = playlist.replace('\', '/')
    return playlist`     Not work

Comment: What exactly does not work? What or who is "He"? Do you see any error messages? If so, please include them in the question.

Comment: You essentially want to change `'C:\...'` to start with `'file:///'` so use an if statement to check for it, if true then concatenate it.

Comment: essentially I would like to change 'C: \ ...' to start with 'file: ///' in order to have both http: ******* that C: \ ******* functioning. an if statement would be fine, but how should I put?